# Get the users download directory

Tags: python, django, directory, download

I'm on my linux server and I want to save something into the downloads folder from the user which is using the website, how do I get the downloads path from the user, when I try to save something in the downloads folder a folder named "downloads" gets created in my root directory, and not in my computers downloads folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may serve a file to a user via the web browser.  It is up to the browser and user to determine whether or not to download that file, and where to store it.  You cannot enumerate a user's filesystem or determine their downloads folder.